# What to set permissions to when developing a wordpress site locally

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I've setup a domain through apache virtual hosts and set the permissions on the public_html directory as $USER:$USER. I also have wordpress installed in public_html/wp

When trying to add a local image to the media part of the site, wordpress threw an error saying it did not have permission to create the required folder to store the image. The directories are set to 755 and files to 644 so I assumed it was the ownership that needed to change. So I ran

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/virtual-host-site.dev/*
```

So my ownership looked like $USER:www-data however, this still didn't give wordpress rights, so I tried

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/virtual-host-site.dev/*
```

which fixed the problem. But then as a user, I have no write access to the  directories. I thought adding $USER to the group www-data

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data  $USER
```

would give $USER rights like www-data, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I keep my folders as 755 and files as 644 while allowing both $USER and wordpress write access to the application directories?

Thanks.

Comment: _"How do I keep my folders as 755 and files as 644 while allowing both $USER and wordpress write access to the application directories?"_ - only by making $USER and "wordpress" one and the same user, of course - because files and folders can only have one owner.

Comment: Then is the question, "how do I make $USER and wordpress one and the same user"?

Comment: No, the question is rather why are you opposed to setting proper permissions to allow group access.

Comment: So I need to set the all or some of the folders as 775 instead of 755? As for why, I'm just paranoid about the so called security threats I hear having folders something other than 755.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved this by changing my dev directory to www-data:www-data and changing my themes folder to $USER:www-data with the command

sudo chown -R $USER:www-data wp/wp-content/themes